# Extracting property values from a dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to write a subroutine that will deserialize a dictionary from a .ser file (this bit works fine) and then repopulate several lists from this dictionary (this is the bit I cannot do).

The dictionary contains objects (I think) of a custom class I wrote called "Photo Job" which has properties such as ETA, notes, medium etc. (Declared as such)

```
Dim photoJobs As New Dictionary(Of String, PhotoJob)
```

In short, I want to be able to extract every entry of each specific property into an separate arrays (one for each property) and I can go from there.

Any help would be appreciated, I may be going about this completely the wrong way, I'm new to VB. The relevant code is below:

Photo Job Class:

```
<Serializable()> _Public Class PhotoJob

Private intStage As Integer                             'Declare all local private variables
Private ID As String
Private timeLeft As Integer
Private material As String '
Private note As String
Private path As String
Private finished As Boolean = False
'Declare and define properties and methods of the class
Public Property productionStage() As Integer
    Get
        Return intStage
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        intStage = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property photoID() As String
    Get
        Return ID
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        ID = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ETA() As Integer
    Get
        Return timeLeft
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        timeLeft = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property medium() As String
    Get
        Return material
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        material = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property notes() As String
    Get
        Return note
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        note = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property imagePath() As String
    Get
        Return path
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        path = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property complete() As Boolean
    Get
        Return finished
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        finished = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub nextStage()
    If intStage < 4 Then
        intStage += 1
    ElseIf intStage = 4 Then
        intStage += 1
        finished = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Subroutines involved in de/serialisation:

```
 Private Sub BackupAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackupAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
    Dim backupFile As New FileStream(Strings.Replace(Strings.Replace(Now, ":", "_"), "/", ".") & ".ser", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    formatter.Serialize(backupFile, photoJobs)
    backupFile.Close()
    MsgBox("Collection saved to file")
End Sub

Private Sub RestoreFromFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RestoreFromFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
    With OpenFileDialog                                                                         'Executes the following sets/gets/methods of the OpenFileDialog
        .FileName = ""
        .Title = "Open Image File"
        .InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        .Filter = "Serial Files(*.ser)|*ser"
        .ShowDialog()
    End With
    Dim backupPathStr As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
    Dim deSerializer As New BinaryFormatter
    Dim backupFile As New FileStream(backupPathStr, FileMode.Open)
    photoJobs = deSerializer.Deserialize(backupFile)
    backupFile.Close()

End Sub
```

From what I can see using the autos menu, the saving/restoring of the dictionary works just fine.

Comment: No one can help without knowing whats in the Dictionary.

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I've edited the OP accordingly

Comment: Some code is probably in order so we can see what you mean because Dictionaries cannot *normally* be serialized and it would be nice to see the class since you could easily be using public Fields and not Properties at all.  Show what you have tried.

Comment: Further edited to show code, sorry if I have over complicated this matter by using my terminology incorrectly, as I said, I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: how is `PhotoJobs` declared?  Also, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: you should be able to iterate the dictionary with `For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, photoJob) In PhotoJobs`.  As you do, `kvp.value` will be a reference to the current PhotoJob object you can access the props for.  You should also turn on Option Strict because the result of that Deserialization will be Object not Dictionary.

Comment: 'code' Dim photoJobs As New Dictionary(Of String, PhotoJob) 'code' Like that... and I'm using VS community 2013.

Comment: sorry, can you please explain that kvp thing a bit more, I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Actually wait, got it, I'll add your comment as a solution :)

Comment: The thing about serializing is that there are several serializers and the most common one, XMLSerializer, wont work with standard dictionaries.  Many think that is the only one there is, hence the initial question/comment.  Code *always* breaks thru language barriers and experience levels better than words, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using VS2010+, you can greatly reduce boilerplate code using autoimplemented properties:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class PhotoJob   
    Public Property productionStage() As Integer
    Public Property photoID() As String
    Public Property ETA() As Integer
    etc
End Class
```

That is all that is needed, all the boilerplate code is handled for you.  Second, with this line:

```
photoJobs = deSerializer.Deserialize(backupFile)
```

Your deserialized photojobs will be a generic `Object`, not a `Dictionary`.  You should turn on `Option Strict` so VS will enforce these kinds of errors.  This is how to deserialize to Type:

```
 Using fs As New FileStream(myFileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    PhotoJobs= CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), Dictionary(Of String, PhotoJob))
End Using
```

`Using` closes and disposes of the stream, `CType` converts the Object returned by BF to an actual dictionary

To work with the Dictionary (this has nothing to do with Serialization) you need to iterate the collection to get at the data:

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, PhotoJob) In PhotoJobs
    listbox1.items.Add(kvp.value.productionStage)
    listbox2.items.Add(kvp.value.ETA)
    etc
Next
```

The collection is a made of `(String, PhotoJob)` pairs as in your declaration, and when you add them to the collection.  They comeback the same way.  `kvp.Key` will be the string key used to identify this job in the Dictionary, `kvp.Value` will be a reference to a PhotoJobs object.

As long as VS/VB knows it is a `Dictionary(of String, PhotoJob)`, `kvp.Value` will act like an instance of PhotoJob (which it is).